# How to replace "New Case" button from the lookup with a quick action?

Tags: case-object, livechattranscript, pre-chat-api

I am trying pre-populate values on Case while creating a new case by selecting the below shown button on LiveChatTranscript page. I am not sure where to set the predefined values for this since it is not a Quick Action. Could any help me with how to do that? or replace it with a Quick Action?

[image]

Comment: There is no way to customize this link, unfortunately. You will end up with bunch of ideas in salesforce. You will have to use different approach like first create transcript then provide a action on detail level to create and associate that case wid this transcript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Quick Action for this, and then setting predefined field values as needed, including relating the newly created case to your transcript record. Here is the documentation on [quick action predefined field values](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you, Brandon. I added a new button in Chat Transcript page which invokes a lwc to select case record type, proceed with case creation and associate created case to chat transcript.